# create repeating xml element using java

Tags: java, xml

I am having problems creating an xml doc with the hierarchy I am looking for ..

```
<claimants>
<claimant>
    <Area>Discrimination/Equality</Area>
    <Complaints>1</Complaints>
    <AssocatedComplaints>3</AssocatedComplaints>
 </claimant>
 <claimant>
    <Area>Redundancy</Area>
    <Complaints>1</Complaints>
    <AssocatedComplaints>3</AssocatedComplaints>
 </claimant>
```

I am getting this -

```
<claimants>
<claimant>
    <Area>Discrimination/Equality</Area>
    <Complaints>1</Complaints>
    <AssocatedComplaints>3</AssocatedComplaints>
    <Area>Redundancy</Area>
    <Complaints>1</Complaints>
    <AssocatedComplaints>3</AssocatedComplaints>
    <Area>Terms and Conditions of Employment</Area>
    <Complaints>1</Complaints>
    <AssocatedComplaints>3</AssocatedComplaints>
</claimant>
```

Here is the relevant part of the code, appendchild does not work as I would have expected, I have tried a couple of other options, how can I get the claimant element to populate and repeat ??

```
Document document = new DocumentImpl();
Element claimants = document.createElement("claimants");
Element claimant = document.createElement("claimant");
```

...
...

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next())  {
    // get data in
    String area = rs.getString("Area");
    System.out.println(">> Area : "+area);
    complaints = rs.getString("Complaints");
    System.out.println(">> Complaints : "+ complaints);
    associated = rs.getString("Associated");
    System.out.println(">> Associated : "+associated);

    // write text elements
    Element eArea = document.createElement("Area");
    eArea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(area));
    Element eComplaints = document.createElement("Complaints");
    eComplaints.appendChild(document.createTextNode(complaints));
    Element eAssociated = document.createElement("AssocatedComplaints");
    eAssociated.appendChild(document.createTextNode(associated));

    // append to claimant 
    System.out.println("appending ELEMENTS to claimant");
    claimant.appendChild(eArea);
    claimant.appendChild(eComplaints);
    claimant.appendChild(eAssociated);

    // append to claimants
    System.out.println("appending claimant to claimants");
    claimants.appendChild(claimant);
    //claimants.insertBefore(claimant, claimants.firstChild);

    System.out.println("creating new element claimant");
    Element claimant = document.createElement("claimant");
    }

document.appendChild(claimants);
```

thanks for any help ..

Comment: That's not Javascript (in a browser). Is it JScript?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new `claimaint` for each iteration, *inside* the loop:

```
while (rs.next())  {
  Element claimant = document.createElement("claimant"); // a new claimaint is created for each new row

  // append elements to claimant
  claimant.appendChild(eArea);
  claimant.appendChild(eComplaints);
  claimant.appendChild(eAssociated);

  // append to claimaints
  claimants.appendChild(claimant);
}
```